# How to break up or parse a date string into seperate yy-mm-dd , hh, and mm am or pm

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pull our the Hour, Minutes, yy-mm-dd, and if am or pm from a datestring passed over via an API we are using. Trying to set local JS vars.

I have a string response passed over via an API (`2018-12-31T09:00:00-0600`)

I need to submit a request to another API but I need to pass over the hour, minute, date and am/pm as separate variables.

Local JS vars:

```
  var TK_send_date; //yy-mm-dd
  var TK_send_hour; //01-23
  var TK_send_minute; // 00, 30
  var TK_ampm; // AM or PM
```

API wants this.

```
someAPIFunction(hour, minutes, date, ampm);
```

== UPDATE =========

Here is what I have and only part of it is working.

```
function bookingSuccess(response) {
    console.log("bookingSuccess function called");
    TK_Response = response;
    local_date = new Date(response.data.start); //2018-12-31T09:00:00-0600
    TK_send_hour = local_date.getHours(); // is always 0
    TK_send_hour = local_date.getMinutes(); // is always 0
    TK_send_date = local_date.toISOString().split('T')[0]; // successfully gets the date yy-mm-dd
    if(TK_send_hour < 12) {
      TK_ampm = 'AM';
    } else {
      TK_ampm = 'PM';
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm so confused about what you are asking.

Comment: what does the datestring look like ?

Comment: Since that's an ISO date, you can stick it in `new Date(variable)` to get a Date object, and then you can use the various methods off of Date to get what you want.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype

Answer (score 0):

This was the best I could do for you. It's just a lot of formatting and method invoking.

```
 var today = new Date(); 
 var am_or_pm = today.toLocaleString([], { hour:'numeric', hour12: true });

 var TK_send_date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
 var TK_send_hour = today.getHours();
 var TK_send_minute = today.getMinutes(); 
 var TK_ampm = am_or_pm.slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are details missing from your description, such as what to do about time zones.  If time-zone aware, your solution looks okay except you need `var` on your locals and you're setting the hour from the minute at line 6.  Since your second API wants AM/PM, I'm guessing it also wants 12-hour time, so you'll need to adjust the hour.

If you want a solution that is instead time-zone naive you could use a [regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) to extract the fields you want from the data, and returns them in a dictionary.

```
/* Parse date expected in format 2018-12-31T09:00:00-0600
   @param string The date to be parsed.
   @return Dictionary with values in keys, or null on bad data. */
function parse_date (string) {
    var pattern = /(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)/;
    var matches = pattern.exec (string);
    if (matches == null) return null;
    var hr24 = parseInt (matches [2]);
    return {
        'date': matches [1],
        'hour': hr24 == 0 ? 12 : hr24 > 12 ? hr24 - 12 : hr24,
        'ampm': hr24 < 12 ? "am" : "pm",
        'minute': parseInt (matches [3])
    }
}

console.log (parse_date ("2018-12-31T09:27:00-0600"))
console.log (parse_date ("2018-12-31T14:29:00-0500"))
console.log (parse_date ("2018-12-31T00:29:00-0500"))
console.log (parse_date ("2018-12-31T12:29:00-0500"))
console.log (parse_date ("2018-12-31T13:29:00-0500"))
console.log (parse_date ("2018-12-31Tbjdfjdkfj0600"))
```

This outputs:

```
{ date: '2018-12-31', hour: 9, ampm: 'am', minute: 27 }
{ date: '2018-12-31', hour: 2, ampm: 'pm', minute: 29 }
{ date: '2018-12-31', hour: 12, ampm: 'am', minute: 29 }
{ date: '2018-12-31', hour: 12, ampm: 'pm', minute: 29 }
{ date: '2018-12-31', hour: 1, ampm: 'pm', minute: 29 }
null
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I've created a very simple time utility object. It's pretty straight forward should achieve what you need. To use this in your code, you would replace the `Date.now()` argument to the `TimeUtil` constructor with your `response.data.start`.

```js
function TimeUtil(ms) {
  this.src = new Date(ms);
  this.day = this.src.getDate();
  this.month = this.src.getMonth() + 1;
  this.year = this.src.getFullYear();
  this.hour = this.src.getUTCHours() - (this.src.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
  this.minute = this.src.getUTCMinutes();

  this.getYear = function(digits) {
    var s = this.year.toString();
    return s.substring(s.length - digits, s.length);
  };

  this.getHour = function() {
    var s = this.hour.toString();
    if (s.length < 2) {
      s = `0${s}`;
    }
    return s;
  };

  this.getMinute = function() {
    var s = this.minute.toString();
    if (s.length < 2) {
      s = `0${s}`;
    }
    return s;
  };

  this.getSuffix = function() {
    return this.hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  }
}

var util = new TimeUtil(Date.now());
var TK_send_date = `${util.getYear(2)}-${util.month}-${util.day}`;
var TK_send_hour = util.getHour();
var TK_send_minute = util.getMinute();
var TK_ampm = util.getSuffix();

console.log(TK_send_date);
console.log(TK_send_hour);
console.log(TK_send_minute);
console.log(TK_ampm);
```